# Disable double click event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Does anyone know how I can disable a double click event with **jQuery** or **CSS**?

```
<td class="example"></td>
```

Comment: By default a double click on a `td` selects the text - are you trying to prevent text selection? If some other action occurs on double click of the element, just remove the event handler. You could potentially use `pointer-events: none` in your CSS, but this will stop all mouse-related events from firing on the element, not just double-click

Comment: I only want to disable a specific one, not all

Comment: Right, but *disable what action specifically*. What action that double clicking performs are you trying to prevent...?

Comment: `ondblclick="return false"` ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$('selector').unbind('dblclick')
```